# How to avoid template from getting repeated or stuck in angular during component Interaction?

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

I am working on an angular15 project. I am trying to understand @Input decorator but my template is getting stuck .

// file 1 app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet> 
<app-learning [pagetitle]="name"></app-learning>
```

// file 2 app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: \['./app.component.css'\]
})
export class AppComponent {
title = "WoRDit";
pagetitle = "wordit";
name = "Rosalin";
}
```

// file 3 learning.component.html ( this is the child component )

```
<head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{header}}</h1>
    <br><br>
    <h1>Second form </h1>
    <div class="container">
        <form name="Login" (submit)= "Evaluate($event)">
            <input class=".styling" type="text" name="email-input" id="email"  [ngClass]="validstatusemail"> <br>
            <span>{{msgemail}}</span><br>
            <input class=".styling" type="password" name="pass-input" id="password" [ngClass]="validstatuspassword"> <br>
            <span>{{msgpassword}}</span><br>
            <input class=".styling" type="submit" value="Login" id = "button">
            <br><br>
        </form>
    </div>
<h1>{{pagetitle}}</h1>
</body>
```

// file 4 learning.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-learning',
templateUrl: './learning.component.html',
styleUrls: \['./learning.component.css'\]
})
export class LearningComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit{

ngOnInit(){

}

ngOnChanges(){

}

// string interpolation for data binding
title = "Learning Angular";
header = "Learning Angular : Zero to Hero Course";

// form validation : required fields
hasEmail = true;
hasPassword = true;
msgemail = "";
msgpassword = "";
validstatusemail = "";
validstatuspassword = "";

Evaluate(e: any){

    e.preventDefault();
    let email = document.querySelector("#email") as HTMLInputElement;
    let password = document.querySelector("#password") as HTMLInputElement;
    let submission = document.querySelector('#button') as HTMLInputElement;
    
    console.log(email.value)
    console.log(password.value)
    console.log(submission.value)
    
    if ( email.value == "" && password.value == "" ){
      this.hasEmail = false;
      this.hasPassword = false;
      this.validstatusemail = 'text-danger';
      this.validstatuspassword = 'text-danger';
      this.msgemail = 'Email is requried';
      this.msgpassword = 'Password is requried';
    }
    
    else if ( email.value == "" && password.value != "" ){
      this.hasEmail = false;
      this.hasPassword = true;
      this.validstatusemail = 'text-danger';
      this.validstatuspassword = 'text-success';
      this.msgemail = 'Email is requried';
      this.msgpassword = '';
    }
    
    else if ( email.value != "" && password.value == "" ){
      this.hasEmail = true;
      this.hasPassword = false;
      this.validstatusemail = 'text-success';
      this.validstatuspassword = 'text-danger';
      this.msgemail = '';
      this.msgpassword = 'Password is requried';
    }
    
    else{
      this.hasEmail = true;
      this.hasPassword = false;
      this.validstatusemail = 'text-success';
      this.validstatuspassword = 'text-success';
      this.msgemail = '';
      this.msgpassword = '';
    }

}

@Input()
pagetitle = '';
}
```

There is no error popping up so I have no clue on where to start or what to search. It would be greatly helpful if the community can help me on this. The form is getting repeated twice and I don't know what to do. Similarly the second form is attached in all pages

Comment: Recommended to paste your code to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular) with minimal code to reproduce the issue. So all your code is there for community to investigate.

Comment: If you use `@Input() pagetitle` to use you write `{{pagetitle}}` -you has wrote `{{title}}`. BTW use [[(ngModel)]](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) or [ReactiveForms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) to manage inputs, **not** use javascript and this "ugly" document.querySelector("#email")

Comment: Thank you I shall work on this and update

Comment: I used template driven forms and it help me with solution. Thank you !!